# rdiff-backup over existing backup

Tags: linux, backup

Is it possibly to run a rdiff-backup to an existing old plain tree copy of the files to backup? What options should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know the question is pretty old, but it came up in my search for this exact same thing.

I've found out [[1](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/rdiff-backup-users/2009-01/msg00154.html)] [[2](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/rdiff-backup-users/2006-05/msg00123.html)] that you can simply call:

`rdiff-backup --force source/ dest/`

and rdiff-backup will create the necessary checksumming/data files it needs to convert a plain mirror to an rdiff-backup destination.

Comment: Sounds good! As I am not using rdiff-backup in daily procedure now, may I ask if you tried this successfully?

Comment: @dronus: Yes. I tried it shortly after posting this and it worked fine.

Comment: --force will override the existing backup. If the intention is to use an existing destination because it already contains a copy of the source, then that purpose is defeated.

Comment: This is wrong. **The number [2] reference tells it: "just back up to the same directory with the --force option (first time) and it will effectively do an rsync"**. The number [1] reference tells it wrong. Already tested it... I erased my backup's previous good version using it!

Comment: @SmallBoy - If the answer is incorrect, you should comment (which you have), and downvote the answer.  However, submitting an edit, saying something is wrong is what you shouldn't do.  The edit you proposed won't get approved.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like what you're describing is [rsync(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync). I don't know how rdiff is different from a rsync, but I know that rsync only needs either (1) an rsync daemon listening on the remote system, tcp/873 by default, or (2) an ssh daemon listening on the remote system, tcp/22 by default. There may also be other ways of connecting the system.

Comment: rdiff seems to be based on rsync, and rsync can be used to sync two directories. However, rdiff-backup stores versionated backups, and uses its special metadata therefore. The question was how to make an existing simple copied backup rdiff-backup compatible without copying the whole data again. Maybe its not possible as rdiff-backup collects information while copying (checksums / hashes or soemthing else).